# Discord Bot Playing Audio but no Sound Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a discord bot that joins voice chat, plays audio, then leaves. I am very new to coding and am following a youtube tutorial and I am trying to get the bot to play audio for the first time. The bot successfully joins the voice chat, and it has the green circle around it as if its playing audio, but there is no sound coming out. I believe I have the mp3 is in the right location.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from asyncio import sleep
import random
import nacl

TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ITS WORKING")
    print("------------------------")


@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("ITS WORKING")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('mo.mp3')
        player = voice.play(source)

    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel, you must be in a voice channel to run this command")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I left the voice channel")
    
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def mo(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source= FFmpegPCMAudio('mo.wav')
        player = voice.play(source)

    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")


client.run(TOKEN)
```